# Payload encryption for Legacy web application Struts 1.1

Tags: java, encryption, web-applications, struts-1, payload

Our Web Application is built with Struts 1.1 around 2007. Now the security Auditor has raised that all request and response payload needs to be encrypted.

what startegies can be adopted to do the payload encryption? there are like 1000's of JSP. We have to change indivdual JSP and JS for all the server call

is it even possible to comply to the observation ?

Any help is hugely appreciated

Comment: By any chance would the Auditor be refering to encrypt the channel using TLS (https)?

Comment: Hey,  Https is implemented. The Auditor says both, payload as well as https, is required

Comment: Can you specify where should the palyload be encrypted because the request and the response while in transit is already encrypted with TLS, once on the client it needs to be unencrypted to be of any use, and in the server it also needs to be unecrypted to be processed. So you will need to provide some more info about where it should be encrypted.

Comment: you are right https is already providing channel encryption. Auditors concern is if somebody is able to perform Man in Middle Attack then the request and response is available to him as plain text. So to add extra level of security. is it even possible to encrypt indiv req/res for an old application.

Comment: I think they are chasing ghosts. They should explain how such attack would be done and in that case how is it that adding an additional layer of encryption would be inmune to someone with the resources to hack TLS.

Comment: Man... Auditors using burp tool to intercept request, response. now the data is sensitive. I tried to reason with them. I am looking all over the internet to find some way direction/way to achieve this. Thanks mate

Comment: This makes no sense. A MitM attack would get the HTTPS-encrypted data. If your server is configured correctly, e.g., no HTTP entry points/HSTS policy/etc, a MitM attack is difficult.

Comment: I agree with you @DaveNewton. The req/res is visible as plain text in burp tool and that is what has raised everyones concern.

Comment: @cjava If the app doesn’t use HSTS, or the user accepts an untrusted certificate, sure. HSTS is the canonical solution (forces browser to use secure connection only to the server, not proxies).

Comment: FYI for the burp tool to work and be able to intercept the https requests, you must hack the browser by installing the Burp's certificate. The browser must "trust" burp. Just by itself burp can't hack https.